# Maven: copy local jar to target dir

Tags: java, maven

I want a local jar located in `C:/myLibs/TDKLogging/TDKLogging-2.1.6.jar`
to be copied to my target dir when generating the war, so I modified my pom as follows:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBossNexus</id>
        <name>JBoss Nexus Repository Manager</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>https://webgate.tdk.com/JBoss/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
       <id>my-local-repo</id>
       <url>file://C:/myLibs/</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>tdk.com.iot.log</groupId>
            <artifactId>TDKLogging</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
..
```

But I got this error

```
  Could not find artifact tdk.com.iot.log:TDKLogging:jar:2.1.6 in tdkPublicRepository (https://webgate.tdk.com/JBoss/nexus/content/groups/public)
```

How to tell maven to search the artifact in a specific repo ????  Can a project work with more than 1 repo at the same time ???? because I only have 1 jar in the local repo, the others ones are stored in the public repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may have more than one repo specified.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>Webgate repository</id>
     <url>https://webgate.tdk.com/JBoss/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
     <id>JBoss repository</id>
     <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
     <id>java.net</id>
     <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

What about your particular situation - you have to add your jar and pom to your local repository. You have to run few commands.

Check this
[How to include custom library into maven local repository?](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/)

and this [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Comment: oh, I see. check the repo you've provided. It's not working